# Complicated Split, merge, and pivot multiple data frames in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two pandas dataframe they must be merge and pivot. in one of the dataframes, a column is a string and comma separated. The dataframes are

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

tableA = [(100, 'chocolate, sprinkles'),
     (101, 'chocolate, sprinkles'),
     (102, 'glazed')]
labels = ['product', 'tags']
dfA = pd.DataFrame.from_records(tableA, columns=labels)

tableB = [('A', 100),
       ('A', 101),
       ('B', 101),
       ('C', 100),
       ('C', 102),
       ('B', 101),
       ('A', 100),
       ('C', 102)]
labels = ['customer', 'product']
dfB = pd.DataFrame.from_records(tableB, columns=labels) 

dfA:
     product                  tags
 0      100  chocolate, sprinkles
 1      101  chocolate, sprinkles
 2      102                glazed
dfB:
   customer  product
 0        A      100
 1        A      101
 2        B      101
 3        C      100
 4        C      102
 5        B      101
 6        A      100
 7        C      102
```

and the result must be like

```
 customer   sprinkles   chocolate   glazed
 A          ?            ?              ?
 B          ?            ?              ?   
 C          ?            ?              ?
```

I have tried various functions but I got failed. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

some of my codes, I know this won't work, but it should give you a sense of what I tried to do:

```
dfC=dfB.merge(dfA, left_on='product', right_on='product')
print(dfC)
```

which led to

```
        customer  product                  tags
 0        A      100  chocolate, sprinkles
 1        C      100  chocolate, sprinkles
 2        A      100  chocolate, sprinkles
 3        A      101  chocolate, sprinkles
 4        B      101  chocolate, sprinkles
 5        B      101  chocolate, sprinkles
 6        C      102                glazed
 7        C      102                glazed
```

and,

```
dfS = pd.DataFrame(dfC.tags.str.split(',').tolist(),index=dfC.customer).stack()
dfS = dfS.reset_index()[[ 'customer',0]] 
dfS.columns = ['var1', 'var2'] 
print(dfS)
```

which led to:

```
     var1        var2
0     A   chocolate
1     A   sprinkles
2     C   chocolate
3     C   sprinkles
4     A   chocolate
5     A   sprinkles
6     A   chocolate
7     A   sprinkles
8     B   chocolate
9     B   sprinkles
10    B   chocolate
11    B   sprinkles
12    C      glazed
13    C      glazed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your combine dataframe `dfs` you can use `pd.crosstab` to get the counts of customers tag usages

```
pd.crosstab(dfs.var1,dfs.var2)

var2  chocolate  glazed  sprinkles
var1
A             3       0          3
B             2       0          2
C             1       2          1
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to strip your var2:

```
dfS['var2'] = dfS['var2'].str.strip()
```

to remove space, then you can create a column for each tags such as:

```
dfS['chocolate'] = dfS['var2'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 'chocolate' else 0)
dfS['sprinkles'] = dfS['var2'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 'sprinkles' else 0)
dfS['glazed'] = dfS['var2'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 'glazed' else 0)
```

and then you can `groupby` var1 and aggregate as sum the other columns, such as:

```
dfS.groupby('var1').agg(sum).reset_index().rename(columns ={'var1':'customer'})
```

the output looks like:

```
  customer  chocolate  sprinkles  glazed
0        A          3          3       0
1        B          2          2       0
2        C          1          1       2
```

Comment: Thanks. but as you can see although the number of chocolates and sprinkles are same in the original data frame in the result only one of them has value. It happened to me when I used table_pivot directly. Any suggestion for that ?

Comment: Sorry, I added the strip() to remove space in the column var2 (hidden space are always tricky to me)